# In Spring MockMVC tests, how to chain visit of several webpages?

Tags: java, spring, testing

I have a web application that requires Login. Upon login success, many session attributes are loaded, which will be needed by subsequent navigation of other web pages.

I am testing this web application using Spring test framework 4.12, using MockMVC.

How do I chain a second page visit action after the login page visit? Something like:

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/login").session(session).param("username", "Jack").param("password","Jack'sPassword"))
               .perform(get("/anotherPage")).andExpect(/*some session attribute are successfully loaded*/)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use andDo method to chain your requests

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/login").session(session)
       .param("username","Jack").param("password","Jack'sPassword"))
       //Expectations on the first request
       .andExpect(status().ok())
       //Then chain the request
       .andDo(
           result -> mockMvc.perform(get("/anotherPage")).andExpect(/*some session    attribute are successfully loaded*
       )
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get a type mismatch: andDo() expects a ResultHandler while perform() returns a ResultActions. The only way around this seems to be to write a custom ResultHandler that does the nested mockMvc.perform().

Comment: You shouldn't stop after mockMvc.perform(), may be do mockMvc.perform(...something...).andDo(print())

Comment: This worked for me `.andDo(result -> this.mockMvc.perform(get("/another"))).andExpect(...);`

Comment: Extra tip: It's possible to chain multiple andDo one inside the other, but each "result" MUST have a different name.

Answer (score 4):

In version 5.0.0 you can configure MockMvc to preserve the session between performing calls.

```
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders
    .webAppContextSetup(context)
    .apply(sharedHttpSession())
    .build();
```

see:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-server-setup-steps

Comment: I'm using @AutoConfigureMockMvc. Is there a way to persist session across consecutive perform() calls? I tried chaining calls using andDo(result -> mockMvc.perform(...)) but the result is the same.